# 1990-2000s mecha anime series or movie, white mecha, wings, and pilot sacrifice

Tags: story-identification, tv, anime, mecha

Looking for a mecha anime, either a series or movie between 1990 and early 2000s.

All I remember is the mecha being white and wielding a sword. I don’t recall if the pilot had angel type wings or the mecha did.

The scene I remember most vividly is the pilot sacrificing himself and slowly dying within the mecha armor somewhere in a forest. I remember opera type music playing in the battle prior to the pilot's death.

I’ve watched *The Vision of Escaflowne* and *Cybuster* since the armor is similar to what I remember but neither had the scene I just mentioned. If I recall correctly it was on Cartoon Network/Adult Swim. Currently watching *Gundam Wing* in my attempt to locate it.

Comment: Have you taken a look at Evangelion? In the End of Evangelion there are white mecha with Angel wings. It fits your time frame and there was a weapon referred to as a progressive sword.The forest scene does not fit but there are certainly character deaths.

Comment: Evangelion would be my guess as well, especially if Escaflowne has already been ruled out.

Comment: @dominicfonde Could the mech pilot have been female?  Because if so it fits Neon Genesis Evangelion, episode 23 pretty well.

Comment: As I recall there were two female mech pilots. If it is Evangelion then the character of Asuka would be a good fit.

Comment: @Ryan_L good catch have not watched the series for years. Episode 23 seems a close match.

Comment: Have you checked out Rahxephon? The main mecha is white with angel wings on its head.

Comment: Could [Mobile Suit Gundam 0080: War in the Pocket](https://gundam.fandom.com/wiki/Mobile_Suit_Gundam_0080:_War_in_the_Pocket). Everybody dies!

Answer (score 2):

Based on the discussion in the comments I am going to suggest you are looking for Neon Genesis Evangelion. The original anime series was made in the 1990's and was subsequently followed by a mini-series and then an anime film remake series. There have a been a couple of english dubs any one of which you could have seen.

There are mecha, multiple images and references to angles, weapons that appear as giant swords or knives and classical music scoring scenes. It has been suggested in the comments by @Ryan_L that you may be thinking of episode 23. Episode 23 can be seen here... although the image quality is very low. It does take place in a forest and is very likely what you describe.

I wonder if you are thinking of the ending of the End of Evangelion which features multiple white mocha with large wings. You can see a youtube clip here...

Comment: Unfortunately it’s not Neon Genesis Evangelion. Should of mentioned the pilot was most likely male and the mecha was on the good guys side. I have a gut feeling it’s one of the many Gundam shows from the 90s or early 2000s.

Comment: There were male EVA pilots and the EVA's were made by the humans.